# Quarkus - global application.properties in multi-module project

Tags: gradle, properties, multi-module, quarkus, microprofile

In my multi module Gradle project I have some properties that I wish to apply to all my modules without duplicating them in each module, like logging formats and some URLs.

I´ve tried to put them into my common module, but it seems as long as it isn´t any application module those properties are ignored.

**Is there any possible solution to set properties globally?**

Comment: Quarkus properties are based off of MicroProfile config, which allows setting properties using JVM system properties or environment variables. Also, keep in mind that by default Gradle does _not_ propagate system properties from the Gradle process to any launched process such as test/dev JVMs

Comment: @AndyGuibert Oh, you are right, thank you. Haven´t thought about that